# Windows Phone 7 and Web Services

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need a very basic step by step walk through on calling a webservice from WP7.  Does anyone have any good simple examples of this?

I'm not sure if this what they are calling "Push Notification" or something totally different.  I need a super simple basic example.

Also does anyone know, can you only call .Net webservices or can you call a .PHP page that returns JSON Data to pass in to the WP7 phone?

Thanks!

Comment: I found this one useful: http://hadyelsahar.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/webservices-in-wp7/ It gives you a brief idea about web services and contains a demo as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call any type of web service that talks http.

There are a variety of approaches and types of web services.

Here is a walkthrough of interfacing with a WCF Service.

[AfricanGeek Silverlight 3 Video Tutorials](http://www.africangeek.com/) (scroll right to 1st tute)

Here is a code sample demonstrating use of HttpWebRequest and WebClient.

[WebClient, HttpWebRequest and the UI Thread on Windows Phone 7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8)